# Elixir - How do I split a string into a list by every 3 characters

Tags: elixir

if I have the string `"UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU"` how to I turn it into a list split up by every 3 characters into `["UGG", "UGU", "UAU", "UAA", "UGG", "UUU"]`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your string contains only ASCII characters and your string's `byte_size` is a multiple of 3, there's a really elegant solution using a lesser known Elixir feature: binary comprehensions:

```
iex(1)> string = "UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU"
"UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU"
iex(2)> for <<x::binary-3 <- string>>, do: x
["UGG", "UGU", "UAU", "UAA", "UGG", "UUU"]
```

This splits the string into chunks of 3 bytes. This will be much faster than splitting on codepoints or graphemes but will not work correctly if your string contains non-ASCII characters. (In that case I'd go with @michalmuskala's answer.)

Edit: Patrick Oscity's answer reminded me that this can also work for codepoints:

```
iex(1)> string = "αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψ"
"αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψ"
iex(2)> for <<a::utf8, b::utf8, c::utf8 <- string>>, do: <<a::utf8, b::utf8, c::utf8>>
["αβγ", "δεζ", "ηθι", "κλμ", "νξο", "πρς", "στυ", "φχψ"]
```

Comment: Usually you want to split at grapheme boundary, not just codepoints. For a lot this will work, but it will break, for example, for emojis. For instance, `"ébcde"` (first letter is two codepoints, e and combining acute), is going to become `["éb", "cde"]`

Comment: You made me ashamed to be here as "UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU" is an exact match in the test suite …

Answer (score 21):

```
"UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU"
|> String.codepoints
|> Enum.chunk_every(3)
|> Enum.map(&Enum.join/1)
```

I am also wondering if there's a more elegant version

Answer (score 16):

This can be achieved using the `Stream.unfold/2` function. In a way, it's the opposite of `reduce` - reduce allows us collapsing a collection into a single value, unfold is about expanding a single value into a collection.

As a generator for `Stream.unfold/2` we need a function that returns a tuple - first element is the next member of the generated collection, and the second is the accumulator we're going to pass into the next iteration. This describes exactly the function `String.split_at/2`. Finally, we need a termination condition - `String.split_at("", 3)` will return `{"", ""}`. We're not interested in empty strings, so it should be enough to process our generated stream until we encounter the empty string - this can be achieved with `Enum.take_while/2`.

```
string
|> Stream.unfold(&String.split_at(&1, 3)) 
|> Enum.take_while(&(&1 != ""))
```

Comment: A very nice use case, I also see `unfold` like an `iterate` with memory.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility would be using `Regex.scan/2`:

```
iex> string = "abcdef"
iex> Regex.scan(~r/.{3}/, string)
[["abc"], ["def"]]

# In case the number of characters is not evenly divisible by 3
iex> string = "abcdefg"
iex> Regex.scan(~r/.{1,3}/, string)
[["abc"], ["def"], ["g"]]

# If you need to handle unicode characters, you can add the `u` modifier
iex> string = "abc"
iex> Regex.scan(~r/.{1,3}/u, string)
[[""], ["abc"]]
```

Or using a recursive function, which is a bit verbose but should IMO be the best performing solution using eager evaluation:

```
defmodule Split do
  def tripels(string), do: do_tripels(string, [])

  defp do_tripels(<<x::utf8, y::utf8, z::utf8, rest::binary>>, acc) do
    do_tripels(rest, [<<x::utf8, y::utf8, z::utf8>> | acc])
  end

  defp do_tripels(_rest, acc) do
    Enum.reverse(acc)
  end
end

#  in case you actually want the rest in the result, change the last clause to
defp do_tripels(rest, acc) do
  Enum.reverse([rest | acc])
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try

```
List.flatten(Regex.scan(~r/.../, "UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU"))
```

You will get

```
["UGG", "UGU", "UAU", "UAA", "UGG", "UUU"]
```

Source from documentation:

[scan method](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3)

[flatten method](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#flatten/1)

Comment: Clean and elegant, I like it!

Answer (score 4):

How about using [String.split](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3):

```
iex> String.split("UGGUGUUAUUAAUGGUUU", ~r/.{3}/, include_captures: true, trim: true)
["UGG", "UGU", "UAU", "UAA", "UGG", "UUU"]
```